# Return index of every non-zero element in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know there is a way to return the index of the maximum element in an array in python: `numpy.argmax()`. Is there a way to return index of every non-zero element?

For example

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

to

```
[[1, 2, ...,6],
[1,2,...6,8],
...
...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
x = np.asarray([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1])
In [129]: np.nonzero(x)
Out[129]: (array([1, 2, 3, 5]),)
```

See: [[1]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero), [[2]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html#numpy.argwhere), [[3]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html#numpy.flatnonzero)

Comment: Yes. I cannot believe why I did not get right answer from google.